# Can't convert and SELECT simple Epoch Timestamp from last 24 hours in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

i have a very simple time date column with "TEXT" type that stores Epoch Timestamp (1595876617)

i want to select the columns that are only in the last 24 hours.. i tried UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_TIMESTAMP and a lot more i can't get it done

```
SELECT * FROM stories WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_date) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) order by id desc;

SELECT * FROM stories WHERE time_date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

SELECT * FROM news WHERE time_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

**I tried a lot more nothing worked im stil getting results older than 24 hours.. what am i doing wrong?**

Comment: check this = SELECT * FROM news  WHERE  CONVERT(date, time_date) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())

Answer (score 1):

A simple and efficient approach is to compute the timestamp from one day ago, and use for filtering:

```
where time_date > unix_timestamp() - 24 * 60 * 60
```

`unix_timestamp()`, when called without an argument, gives you the *current* epoch, from which you can substract 24 hours as seconds. This is probably more efficient than nesting a function call `now()`.

MySQL will convert the `TEXT` value to an integer to perform the comparison, so there is no need for explicitly casting `time_date`. But, although implicit, conversion does happen. I would highly recommend changing the datatype of the column to `int`.

Comment: thanks a lot .. i tried unfortunately it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` return a number.
The statement should look like :

```
SELECT *
FROM stories
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
```

Comment: it didn't work it still give me results from 3 years